# Can I add css syntax into "text" property on select2?

Tags: javascript, css, json, jquery-select2

I just want to change some color on my "text" on select2, but it's not rendered.

```
results.push({
  id: item.kode_mobil,
  text: item.tipe_mobil + " (<span style='color:red'>"+item.nomor_polisi+"</span>)",
});
```

but it ends like this
[image]

Sorry for my english.
Thanks

Comment: use the `html` property ?

Comment: what is `results`? we need more context.

Comment: yes, I think. or what should i do?

Comment: I just want some text colored into red @cambunctious where should i put the style?

Comment: Try this:
`results.push({
  id: item.kode_mobil,
  text: item.tipe_mobil + item.nomor_polisi.fontcolor("red"),
});`

Comment: I need to see more code in order to understand what `results.push(...)` does

Comment: @sysquare not working :( it ends like the picture.

Comment: Here it is @cambunctious [link](https://jsfiddle.net/v1f3k7km/)

Comment: looks like `select2` does not support custom html within items

Comment: I think so @cambunctious

Answer (score 0):

You can add css

Suppose your select tag class name is '.select'

then

```
.select option
{
color:red
}
```